# keil uVision - Logic Analyzer

Tags: keil, analyzer

How can i read a file with extension *.uvla ?

i tried to open the file with Excel.

goal: I want to send the data read with keil µVision's logic analyzer to MATLAB.
Problem: I don't know how to open the saved data which is read signal values because I don't know how to work with *.uvla extension data.